# Switching Kafka from Kraft to Zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kraft

I have a recent Kafka cluster which uses Kraft. I am facing some problems with it and it is possibly due to use of Kraft. I wish to switch to Zookeeper without losing data. Downtime is okay. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there isn't a documented process to downgrade a cluster from KRaft to ZooKeeper.

If you've found an issue with KRaft, you should report it to the Kafka project via a [Jira ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/KAFKA) so it can get fixed.

Assuming your KRaft cluster is somewhat functional, a way to preserve your data is to create a new cluster (running ZooKeeper) and use a tool like [MirrorMaker](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#georeplication) to migrate your data.